# Symfony2 Large File Uploads

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to upload large files (5-8Mb) in my Symfony2 projects. For some reason anytime I upload anything larger than 2Mb the script bombs out. I can upload anything smaller than 2Mb. I have changed my php.ini file and php -i reflects these changes. I have restarted apache. What else do i need to do to make these larger file upload work. Thanks.

Comment: check `phpinfo()` from browser `php -i` will so the settings for the CLI which may not be the same

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue before; try a chunking method of uploading. Most likely the script is exceeding the max execution time. So (without knowing what your logic looks like) have a function that sends the request (say 1MB) to another file that reads the input stream of the binary data within a while loop and continues to execute as long as the content length of the binary data does not equal zero. The while loop writes the data to a temp file and when it hits zero saves it to a permanent directory (or whatever you want to do from there) You can increase the max memory allowed and execution time in php.ini but this introduces security issues and is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

In your current PHP config, you probably limited the max upload size to 2M, so Symfony display the wrong error.

So check your php.ini file (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini on Linux) and increase max_upload_size to fit your field :

upload_max_filesize = 20M

Don't forget to restart apache : apache2ctl restart

Now it should work !